# Where can I find historical data for Europe listed ETFs?

Tags: data, market-data, financial-markets

I'm currently working on building a portfolio optimization tool for European ETFs such as: (SYMBOL/ISIN/description)

- IQQF / IE00B0M63730 / iShares MSCI AC Far East ex-Japan UCITS ETF
- EXW1 / DE0005933956 / iShares EURO STOXX 50 UCITS ETF
- IQQL / IE00B1TXHL60 / iShares Listed Private Equity UCITS ETF
- EXS1 / DE0005933931 / iShares Core DAX UCITS ETF DE
- LSXR8 / IE00B5BMR087 / iShares Core S&P 500 UCITS ETF

Is there a resource, where I can find these as a bulk download (not only individually).

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: Do you have access to Bloomberg? University libraries often have a terminal.

Comment: Currently I don't and we are looking to build a tool that updates daily/ max. weekly so we would need an automatic data feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Bloomberg API:

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/IQQF:GR

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/EXW1:QT

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/IQQL:GR

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/EXS1:TH

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/LSXR8:GR

or try download it manually via:

https://www.finanzen.net/etf/historisch/ishares_core_s&p_500_ucits_etf